# React + React Router + ASP.NET MVC / IIS showing blank page in production only?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, iis, webpack

I'm setting up a simple app using ASP .NET MVC 4 and React / React Router running on IIS. Everything is working fine when running on my local IIS express (the instance that is started by Visual Studio), but when trying to run on production, I get a blank page. **No JS errors or 404s, the bundle is being loaded correctly but not executing.**

I'm totally lost on why this would be working in the local IIS started by VS2013 but not running when moving the project to run as an application on an existing IIS website. Any and all help would be appreciated.

I have only one catch-all route set up in `RouteConfig.js` which serves `Index.cshtml` using `View()`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My single `.cshtml` file is:

```
<div id="app"></div>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/dist/bundle.js")
```

And my `webpack.config.js` file is:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/App.jsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/components'),
            Pages: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/pages'),
            Util: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/util'),
            Styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/scss/'),
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was not a problem with my config but rather with my React Router. The dev site's base URL is just "/", but the version I was deploying to has a base URL of "/appName". Setting the "basename" prop of my BrowserRouter fixed the issue.